# How to fix "use of deleted function" when using mutex and condition variable as member?

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable

I am doing some multi-threading exercise and couldn't get this code pass compilation. I search online but so far not exactly sure about the cause.

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class FooBar {
  private:
    int n;

  public:
    FooBar(int n) {
        this->n = n;
    }

    void foo(function<void()> printFoo) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printFoo();
        }
    }

    std::mutex foo_mtx;
    std::condition_variable foo_cv;
};

void printFoo()
{
    cout << "foo";
}

int main ()
{
    FooBar foobar(10);
    std::thread foo_thread = std::thread(&FooBar::foo, foobar, printFoo);
    foo_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs well if I don't add mutex and condition variable.

```
error: use of deleted function ‘FooBar::FooBar(const FooBar&)’
error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
error: use of deleted function ‘std::condition_variable::condition_variable(const std::condition_variable&)’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are copying a `fooBar`.  The compiler says you are not allowed to.  You are not allowed to because a mutex cannot be copied.

```
std::thread foo_thread = std::thread(&FooBar::foo, std::ref(foobar), printFoo);
```

this will make that specific compiler error go away.  Without building it I cannot be certain there aren't other problems.

```
std::thread foo_thread = std::thread([&foobar]{ foobar.foo(printFoo); });
```

this is a more sane way to solve the same problem.  Lambdas are usually a better plan than using INVOKE based interfaces.

Comment: @NadavB The OP's code copies a mutex.  You can't do that.  My code doesn't copy a mutex.  So I don't get the error the OP does.  Not doing the thing that causes an error results in there not being an error.  I, as mentioned, make no guarantee my code *works* -- I don't know what context the OP's code is in.  Not-copying that mutex could cause other problems.  I just pointed out what is causing the OP's problem.